# Adding list elements to the database using LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

When creating an application, I came across a problem. I have created a data model and there are 2 classes among them (there are more but in the example it's about these 2)

The first class concerns WZ documents:

```
public partial class WZ_DWS_SITO
{
    public string WZ { get; set; }
    public string WZ_DATA { get; set; }
    public string WZ_CZAS { get; set; }
    public string WZ_POZYCJA { get; set; }
    public string MATERIAL { get; set; }
    public string PARTIA { get; set; }
    public string ZAKLAD { get; set; }
    public string SKLAD { get; set; }
    public decimal WZ_ILOSC { get; set; }
    public string ZLECENIE { get; set; }
    public string ZLECENIE_DATA_UTWORZENIA { get; set; }
    public string KUNNR { get; set; }
    public string ZLECENIE_POZYCJA { get; set; }
    public decimal ZLECENIE_CENA_NETTO { get; set; }
    public decimal ZLECENIE_ILOSC { get; set; }
    public decimal ZLECENIE_NETTO { get; set; }
    public decimal ZLECENIE_KOSZT { get; set; }
    public string WWW { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ZLECENIE_CENA_ZAKUPU { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ZLECENIE_ZYSK { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ZLECENIE_MARZA { get; set; }
    public string VE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> WZ_KOSZT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> WZ_NETTO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> WZ_ZYSK { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> WZ_CALA_NETTO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ATP_SKLAD { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ATP_ZAKLAD { get; set; }
    public string DATA_WYCENY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CENA_MINIMALNA { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> WZ_ILOSC_NA_WZ { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ILOSC_60DNI_ABC_5PROCENT { get; set; }
    public string PRZYCZYNA { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    public string L0 { get; set; }
    public string L1 { get; set; }
    public string L2 { get; set; }
    public string NAZWA_KLIENTA { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> INDEKS { get; set; }
    public string NAZWA_MATERIALU { get; set; }
    public string PH { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MARZA_ZLECENIE_ALL { get; set; }
}
```

The second one collects the history of accepted documents:

```
public class HISTORYWZ
{
    public string NrWZ { get; set; }
    public string ODBIORCA { get; set; }
    public string DATAWZ { get; set; }

    public int INDEKS { get; set; }
    public string MATERIAL { get; set; }
    public string PARTIA { get; set; }
    public decimal ILOSC { get; set; }
    public string NAZWA_MATERIALU { get; set; }
    public string PRZYCZYNA { get; set; }
    public decimal CENAMIN { get; set; }
    public decimal CENASPRZ { get; set; }
    public decimal VPRS { get; set; }
    public decimal MARZA { get; set; }

}
```

Chciałbym wyciągając pojedyńczą WZ (która może mieć kilka pozycji) móc wrzucić ją do historii ale tylko elementy które są mi potrzebne.
Wyciągnąłem sobie elementy za pomocą LINQ :

```
EntitiesSito ent = new EntitiesSito();
        dynamic wkaa = datagridview.SelectedItem;
        string actwuzetka = wkaa.WZ.ToString();

        var skad = (from d in ent.WZ_DWS_SITO
                    where d.WZ == actwuzetka
                    select 
                    ).ToList();
```

And I would like to add these elements to the database by assigning that WZ from the WZ_DWS_SITO class corresponds to the number of the WZ from the HistoryWZ class and so on. Then I want to delete the records from the database, but I've already covered myself.

Comment: Just an advice from my point of view: use English language for naming your classes and members. It is useful for everyone: people on SO trying to understand your code; your project which will possibly hire international or/and remote employees or pass external audit in future; and for you personally improving your English, extending your vocabulary and, who knows, working in an international company in the future.

Comment: And for sure use English when you ask question on SO. Perhaps, did you forget to translate one sentence?

Comment: what operation you want to do?

Comment: I want add specyfing range from one table to another table.

Answer (score 0):

```
var skad = (from d in ent.WZ_DWS_SITO
            where d.WZ == actwuzetka
            select new HISTORYWZ()
            {
                //NrWZ = d.WZ_ ,
                //ODBIORCA = d.ODBIORCA,
                //DATAWZ = d.DATAWZ,
                INDEKS = d.INDEKS.Value,
                MATERIAL = d.MATERIAL,
                PARTIA = d.PARTIA,
                ILOSC = d.WZ_ILOSC,
                PRZYCZYNA = d.PRZYCZYNA,
                NAZWA_MATERIALU = d.NAZWA_MATERIALU,
                //CENAMIN = d.WZ_ICENAMIN,
                //CENASPRZ = d.WZ_ICENASPRZ,
                //VPRS = d.WZ_VPRS,
                //MARZA = d.WZ_MARZA,
            }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: do you still need help ?